# White orchids in florida that changed to purple?

Tags: orchids

I have a white orchid plant, this season it produced purple blooms.
My neighbor has the same variety as mine, her orchids were still the normal bright white.
What happened to mine, too much sun,different locations?
Help!!!!

Comment: Hi, Matthew! Can you please post a picture of the plant if you still have it? It would help to answer your question.